# Gitpod self hosted doesn't have bitbucket provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, amazon-eks, gitpod

I have installed gitpod v2022.03.1 for AWS EKS. Everythings works fine, but in git integration page (first page), provider bitbucket is not present.
There are only github and gitlab.

[image]

Is there something wrong?
How can I use bitbucket?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This request is being tracked in the following issue on GitHub.
https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/9172

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the March 2022 release - this feature was released in May 2022. Upgrade to the latest version and it'll be there